# How to select all elements with a class that contains a str?

Tags: css, d3.js, css-selectors

Im trying to select all `<path>`'s but only ones that conatin a class that INCLUDES a str.

as an example if i have 3 elements

```
<h1 class="hello"/>
<h2 class="bye" />
<h3 class="fix" />
```

I want to be able to say everything with a class containing an e, change color to red.

which would make
h1 and h2 red.

Im using d3.selectAll(`path[class=*.${str}]`);

(Doing this with d3.selectAll(`path:not([class=*.${str}`])`) seems to work for selecting everything without that class)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors -  star is on the wrong side

Comment: /* <a> elements whose class attribute contains the word "logo" */
a[class~="logo"] from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Answer (score 3):

Like Pete said, your * is on the wrong side of the equal sign. You also don't need to add `.` in your selector. Something like this should work for you:

`` d3.selectAll(`path[class*=${str}]`) ``